# Can the ErrorProvider be queried to see if it has set any errors?

Tags: c#, winforms, dry, errorprovider

I have this code to do some basic sanity checking before posting a record:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxFirstName.Text))
{
    errorProvider.SetError(textBoxFirstName, "Enter a first name");
}
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLastName.Text))
{
    errorProvider.SetError(textBoxLastName, "Enter a last name");
}
```

...but I want to then do something like this to exit the handler if either of those conditions has been met:

```
if (errorProvider.SetErrorCount > 0) then return;
```

...but I see no way to do that. I don't want to have to write an "OR" statement to see if either of the textBoxes I'm checking are empty and then short circuit the handler that way.

Is there a way to tell whether the errorProvider is "dirty" to avoid cluttery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a method and pass it the error message and the control. Have a counter variable and increase the counter within the method. Here is some pseudocode:

```
private int errorCount;
SetError(Control c, string message)
{
    errorProvider.SetError(c, message);
    errorCount++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the [GetError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.geterror(v=vs.110).aspx) method off of the ErrorProvider.

```
// possibly use a backing field for all controls to evaluate
private readonly Control[] textBoxes = new[] { textBoxFirstName, textBoxLastName };

// helper property to evaluate the controls
private bool HasErrors 
{ 
    get { return textBoxes.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorProvider.GetError(x)); }
}
```

Comment: Impressive, MetroSmurf!